# How to remove index.php from URL?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, symfony1, url-rewriting

I am configuring a project on server which was built using Symfony framework by some other developers. The project is almost configured, except it shows **index.php** into url. It was not showing in the previous server where the site was working fine.

I checked the **settings.yml** file and it has **no_script_name** is set to **on**.
Also I checked on Apache server and rewrite module is already enabled on it.

The code for .htaccess file is on this link
http://pastebin.com/BhquQsk7

Still it is not removing the **index.php** from URL. I also want the folder **web** to be removed from the URL in the later stage but for now, if this one issue gets fixed, it would be very helpful.

Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Comment: How about setting `no_script_name` to `true`? (Which it should be anyway, though on older yaml versions `on` was valid as well.) Regarding removing /web, configure your webserver correctly.

Comment: For your apache configuration, is your DocumentRoot pointing to the web folder?